# Popover is duplicated over and over when opening/hiding keyboard

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uipopovercontroller, uikeyboard

Situation:

I have a `UIViewcontroller` (editViewController) with a UITextfield. The editViewController is my popover contentViewController. The popover is presented with below code:

```
 CGSize size;
 size.width = 620;
 size.height = 500;
 self.myPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]     
                      initWithContentViewController:self.editViewController];

 self.editPopover.popoverContentSize = size;

 [self.editPopover presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame 
                                        inView:self.view
                      permittedArrowDirections:0 // or any other direction
                                      animated:YES];
```

- Xcode Version 4.3.2
- Deployment target iOS 5.0

When the user taps the UITextField, the keyboard pops up like it should. But the popover view keeps getting duplicated when I hide/show the keyboard by using the keyboard hide button and tap the textfield again. Take a look at the popover shadows to see the issue in action.

http://www.tectoys.nl/popover_duplicating.jpg

1. First time popup
2. After about 10x hiding and showing the keyboard. Shadow getting darker because of duplicates.

Does somebody know what causes this issue or can give me a workaround?

Comment: It is important to mention where exactly is the above code placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code sample you provided is being executed every time you are showing the popover then it is because you are creating a new UIPopoverController every time and the old one you created is not being dismissed. Try dismissing the popover before creating the new one:

```
[self dismissFormPopoverAnimated:NO];
self.myPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]     
                  initWithContentViewController:self.editViewController];
```